# How to load a `.xib` / `.nib` file within a framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, nsbundle

I'm working on an iOS library as a Cocoa Pod. In this library, I have a custom view:

```
@interface PlayerView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;

@end
```

```
@implementation PlayerView

- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    [self initialize];
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self initialize];
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlayerView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:contentView];
}

@end
```

In this case `contentView` is the ***entire*** View defined in the `.xib`, which includes an image and a label.

When I build my demo app (and the library) the app runs, but when it comes time to display this view I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/stevenbarnett/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EC244A5F-CE57-4CCD-9BB4-CDC834D74812/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/446EB609-B663-4BD5-8F8D-F22D03BC0B18/bfsdk_Example.app> (loaded)' with name 'PlayerView''
```

Inspecting the `.app` file by hand, the `PlayerView.nib` file can be found buried in the `Frameworks/bfsdk.framework` directory, but I'm guessing since it's not at the root it isn't being located:

[image]
[image]

I've verified:

- That the file owner is set to `PlayerView`
- That `PlayerView.xib` is added to the "copy bundle resources" build phase

How can I load a `.xib` file that's **within** my library from a class that's **within** my library when running an app that just includes my library as a `.framework`?

I believe I could get it working if I manually specified the path to the file with something like:

```
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bfsdk" ofType:@"framework"];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PlayerView"]];
```

However I don't like that this has me hard-coding my framework's name into one of my classes. If I change the name in a year I don't want everything to break because of this one buried line of code that no one remembers exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to use

`[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]`
instead of
`[NSBundle mainBundle]`

So basically [NSBundle mainBundle] returns bundle for current module which is your app, but not the actual framework

Here you can find more details 
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]] what does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754075/nsbundle-bundleforclassself-class-what-does-that-mean)